# Rename a set of files based on regular expression

Tags: regex, linux

I am looking to rename a large number of files that look like this on my ubuntu box:

```
MattTest Season 01 Episode 02 - Episode Name.mkv
```

Would like them to look like this:

```
MattTest S01E02 - Episode Name.mkv
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the below rename command. `\K` keep up the previously matched characters from printing at the final. That is, character which are matched before `\K` are won't taken into consideration.

```
rename 's/^\S+\s+\K(.)\S*\s+(\S+)\s+(.)\S*\s+(\S+)/$1$2$3$4/' *.mkv
```

OR

```
rename 's/^\S+\s+\K(.)\S*\s+(\d+)\s+(.)\S*\s+(\d+)/$1$2$3$4/' *.mkv
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mE5cC1/2)